# Remapping rqt published topics

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing an rqt GUI plugin to set some values in another node, but the rqt plugins seem to always place a namespace in front of my desired published topic name.

For example, my rqt plugin is called "rqt_blueview," and I declare a published topic in the rqt plugin like this...

```
this->max_range_pub_ = getNodeHandle().advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("sonar_max_range", 1);
```

However, the actual topic is published with the following topic name:

```
/rqt_blueview/sonar_max_range
```

I want to publish to `/sonar_max_range`

I tried to remap the topic, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried the following in a launch file:

```
<remap from="/rqt_blueview/sonar_max_range" to="sonar_max_range" />
<node pkg="rqt_blueview" name="rqt_blueview" type="rqt_blueview" />
```

and

```
<remap from="rqt_blueview/sonar_max_range" to="sonar_max_range" />
<node pkg="rqt_blueview" name="rqt_blueview" type="rqt_blueview" />
```

I tried placing the remap tag inside the  tags as well, but with no results. I think this has something to do with how the rqt plugin is loaded into the rqt higher-level Qt window.

I was able to remap the subscribed topic `/sonar_max_range` to `/rqt_blueview/sonar_max_range` on the normal C++ ROS node subscribed side of the topic, but this naming convention doesn't seem natural to me.

Is there a best practice for naming topics when using rqt plugins? I won't want a launch file remapping the rqt GUI plugins since the idea is to open rqt and then "add" the other rqt plugins to the main window.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109371/remapping-rqt-published-topics/) by [Kevin DeMarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5012/kevin-demarco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-29**:
A rqt C++ plugin is not a ROS node but a ROS nodelet. Simply because roscpp does not support to run more then a single node per process. A nodelet always runs in a namespace (http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) but should still be remappable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also tried to remap a topic of C++ rqt plugins but it didn't work.

When I tried with python rqt pluguins, it worked.
So I think this is a bug of C++ rqt plugin.

---

Originally posted by [Yusuke Furuta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2415/yusuke-furuta/) with karma: 28 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0